# Inconsistent result with VC++ versus Java

Tags: java, android, visual-c++, coordinates, trigonometry

I have a long-established routine written in Visual C++ running on PC which calculates the distance between two points on the earth's surface given their lat/long coordinates.

I have converted this to Java as part of a port to Android, but I am getting different results. To investigate the reason for this, I have split a complex trig equation into bits to track what is happening at each step.

However, in Visual C++ the result of the step by step calculation is different from the result obtained from the complex statement, although they should obviously be the same. I would like to know why!

The Java versions yields the same result in both cases, as would be expected.

Here is the Visual C++ code:

```
double CCoord::GetDistanceRadians(double dLatRadians, double dLongRadians)
{
    double dResult;

    // This is the step by step code
    double r1, r2, r3, r4, r5;
    r1 = sin(m_dLatRadians);
    r2 = sin(dLatRadians);
    r3 = cos(dLatRadians);
    r4 = m_dLongRadians - dLongRadians;
    r5 = cos(r4);

    r1 *= r2;
    r2 = r3 * r3;
    r2 *= r5;
    r4 = r1 + r2;

    // This is the original statement: r4 and dResult should be equal
    // (but they aren't)
    dResult = sin(m_dLatRadians) * sin(dLatRadians) +
        cos(m_dLatRadians) * cos(dLatRadians) * cos(m_dLongRadians - dLongRadians);

    // Protect against maths processor inaccuracies
    if ((dResult > 1.0) || (dResult < -1.0))
        dResult = 0.0;
    else
        dResult = acos(dResult);

    return dResult;
}
```

And here is the Java code:

```
    // Return angular distance in radians
private double getDistanceRadians(double dLatRadians, double dLongRadians)
{
    double result;

    // Do JIT test
    checkRadianValues();

            // This is the step by step code
    double r1, r2, r3, r4, r5;
    r1 = Math.sin(m_dLatRadians);
    r2 = Math.sin(dLatRadians);
    r3 = Math.cos(dLatRadians);
    r4 = m_dLongRadians - dLongRadians;
    r5 = Math.cos(r4);

    r1 *= r2;
    r2 = r3 * r3;
    r2 *= r5;
    r4 = r1 + r2;

    // This is the original statement: r4 and result should be equal
    // (and they are)
    result = Math.sin(m_dLatRadians) * Math.sin(dLatRadians) +
                Math.cos(dLatRadians) * Math.cos(dLatRadians) *
                Math.cos(m_dLongRadians - dLongRadians);

    // Protect against maths processor inaccuracies
    if ((result > 1.0d) || (result < -1.0d))
        result = 0.0d;
    else
        result = Math.acos(result);

    return result;
}
```

These are the input and result values:

```
Variable         VC++ value         Java value
m_dLatRadians    0.896808347        0.896808378
m_dLongRadians  -0.047414778(0)    -0.047414778(6)
dLatRadians      0.896192633(9)     0.896192588(9)
dLongRadians    -0.026897463       -0.026897463
r4               1.000218106        1.0002181433
dResult/result   0.999917766        1.0002181433
```

Please can anyone suggest why r4 and dResult should be different in the Visual C++ version?

P.S. I get good final distance results from the VC++ version, and bad final results from Java - nearly all distances come out as zero (the higher level code which calls these routines is not shown because there is a lot of it! However it's the discrepancy I am interested in finding out about).

Comment: dLatRadians is different.  Won't that result in different distances?  Also, is m_dLongRadians a double?  I don't see it in the code.

Comment: Yes, the input parameters (working from the same source data) are slightly different in the low order digits due to differences in conversion accuracy (presumably), but these are not enough to affect the result to the final accuracy I need after further processing. m_dLatRadians is a class member variable and is indeed double - it's following the Microsoft convention for variable naming and the 'd' implies double. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the C++ code

```
cos(m_dLatRadians) * cos(dLatRadians)
```

should be

```
cos(dLatRadians) * cos(dLatRadians)
```

to be consistent with `r2 = r3 * r3;` and match what you are doing in Java.

Also, as [@CaseyB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/236136/caseyb) points out, the `dLatRadians` parameters are different (as are `m_dLatRadians`).

Comment: I don't know how accurate you need to be, but Location will get you bearing and distance between to points using latitude and longitude. For distance, create two locations using the latitude and longitude as constructor arguments and then: float distance = lastLocation.distanceTo(location); Latitude and logitude are in decimal format (floats) such as 29.757343 and -95.416969. You don't need Google Map's api for Location or GeoCoder.

Comment: Bingo! It's a simple typo in the conversion from VC++ (the original, correct version) to Java. Changing the first cos(dLatRadians) to cos(m_dLatRadians) in the Java fixes the error. The discrepancy in the VC++ version is because the step by step version is copied back from the (incorrect) Java version where I first started investigating the problem. As you have put it Dave, it's not the C++ code that needs changing - it's the Java. Thanks.

Comment: Howard - thanks for the suggestion. I will look into changing to use Location if it's simple to do. This code has already been directly ported from the C++. Actually the Java was working before, but I just changed everything from float to double to improve accuracy, and this is where the typo crept in.

Comment: I have now completed testing and after fixing my stupid typo I now get identical results in the final output on both platforms, whereas there were small but noticeable differences in reported distances when the Java version used float. Thanks to everyone who has contributed.